# How do I get all songs from the iPhone music library from a specific year?

Tags: iphone, audio, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

Hi Stack Overflowers, I'm hoping you might be able to help me.

I'm trying to get a collection of all songs in a users iPhone music library from a specific year i.e 2002.

I'm then looking to play the songs through a MPMusicPlayerController.

It seems that you can't set up a MPMediaPropertyPredicate to filter by release date which I think rules that out. What I don't really want to do is have to get a full array of all track release dates and then iterate all the NSDates as I (perhaps wrongly) expect this could be quite slow for large libraries.

What is the best way of achieving this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

here is what you are looking for.

```
allMedia = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
//MPMediaPropertyPredicate *mpp1 = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"2"   forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyRating comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo];
//MPMediaPropertyPredicate *mpp2 = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"Pop" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyGenre comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];
//[allMedia addFilterPredicate:mpp1];
//[allMedia addFilterPredicate:mpp2];

//[myPlayer setQueueWithQuery:allMedia];


NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [allMedia items];

NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i = 0;
int j=0;

NSLog(@"itemCount: %d",[itemsFromGenericQuery count]);

float playsQuery = sliderPlays.value;
if(playsQuery == 20){playsQuery = 10000;}

NSLog(@"sliderRating.value %f  sliderPlays.value %.1f", [sliderRating value],  playsQuery);

while(i++ < 1000){
    int trackNumber = arc4random() % [itemsFromGenericQuery count];
    MPMediaItem *song = [itemsFromGenericQuery objectAtIndex:trackNumber];

    NSString *artistName = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    NSString *title = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSString *rating = [song valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyRating];
    double length = [[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] doubleValue];
    NSNumber *year = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyYear];



    if ([year intValue] >= [def intValue] <= {
        if(j++ > 50){break;}
        NSLog (@"tracknumber: %d j: %d  artistName: %@ title: %@ length: %@ year: %@ playcount: %d",trackNumber, j, artistName, title, length, rating, [playCount intValue]);            
        [mArray addObject:song];            
    }

    if(i++ > 1000)break;
}


MPMediaItemCollection *itemCol = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:mArray];


[myPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:itemCol];


[myPlayer setShuffleMode: MPMusicShuffleModeSongs];
[myPlayer setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeNone];
```

Comment: is MPMediaItemPropertyYear even a valid property? it doesn't exist for me when I try to compile.

Comment: [allMedia items] always return nil